# How to add an extra label in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, jscharts

How do I add an extra label for both the x- and y- (label and data) axes?

```
var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(19, 82, 252, 0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgb(0, 27, 232)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [1583,1620,1665,1769,1683,1678,1699,1791,1868,1876,1886]
            }
        ]

    }

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
```

Comment: Any answer for this question? As it's been so many years

Comment: None. I just left it.